# Convert MATLAB NaN to SQL Null in a cell array

Tags: sql, matlab

I have a large cell array. I have 3 columns which are numerical. Some of the rows in these columns are NaN. This causes an issue when I upload the data to SQL Server (I do not wish to use the matlab function insert).

So far I have tried the below,

```
 export_full = strrep(export_full(:, 6:9),'NaN','NULL');
```

which return the error message

> Cell elements must be character arrays.

Can I use indexing to solve this problem if so how? Performance would be an issue too as its quite a large cell array.

Edit

My cell array is a 10000 x 10 cell
    column 1 is string
    column 2 is string
    column 3 is date
    column 4 to 10 is numerical

Comment: Can you provide a tiny example `export_full`? Is it a cell matrix?

Comment: @Dan please see definition of export_full

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick (credit goes to: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/283735)

```
ind = cellfun(@(x) any(isnan(x(:))), export_full)
export_full(ind) = {'NULL'};
```

Comment: thanks that does indeed work. Can you explain what @(x) actually means?

Comment: It creates what is known as an anonymous function. This allows cellfun to call that function (i.e. `isnan(x(:))` on input `(x)`) for every cell of your array without having to create an actual function anywhere else.